# Nodejs new date on server give different time and also mongodb server

Tags: node.js

I have a client that will send current date time on the client.

example code calling with api:

```js
api.call('find.byDateRange', { from: new Date(2021,11,1, 0,0,0), to: new Date(2021,11,1, 23,59,59, 999) }).then(resp => { // do something})
```

```js
new Date(2021, 11, 1, 0, 0, 0); // { $date: 1638291600000 } // Sat Jan 01 2022 00:00:00 GMT+0700 (Western Indonesia Time)
```

in my case, my client timezone is GMT +7, and the server timezone also GMT +7

when I check on my server (using nodejs)

```js
console.log('from ori', params.from)); // { $date: 1638291600000 }
console.log('from date', new Date(params.from)) // 2021-11-30T17:00:00.000Z
```

it's look like ISO String will make it become UTC,

the next problem is mongodb server that I use is also in the same server.

how to use client datetime as when it sent from client? so it will not minus 7 hours because of time zone, so query from mongodb exact with the selector date time

Comment: new Date of JS will return the date time in locale, database can use the date type as timestamp with timezone or more flexible "timestamp without timezone" (ISO string), so in code, just using new Date().toISOString() to compare or whatever

Comment: "2021-11-30T17:00:00.000Z" is the same as 1638291600000. It is referring to the same point in time. MongoDB also stores Date as number of milliseconds since the Unix epoch. It doesn't matter what human readable expression it is as long as it refers to the same point in time, unless you use your own method to store the date (like as a string?) which could cause matching trouble.

Comment: If you want to avoid timezone mess when designing data structures, always stores Unix timestamp. Never work with timestamp with offset. Take timezone into account only when you finally need to display it to human, do the conversion at the very last moment in frontend.

Answer (score 0):

new Date() or new Date().toISOString() returns without a timezone.

So it does not matter what timezone your server is in.

I recommend using external library to handle it like **moment.js** and **dayjs**

But if you want to print it without external library, you can try `toLocalString` method.

**using system timezone:**

`new Date().toLocaleString()`

**using specific timezone:**

`new Date().toLocaleString('en-US', { timeZone: 'America/New_York' })`